# Flutter TextOverflow.ellipsis вверху

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

Возможно мой вопрос слишком глуп, но я сломал голову. Я хочу простого - чтобы точки обрезали текст снизу, как это обычно и происходит. Но в мое случае происходит так:

[image]

Я использую шрифт SegoeUi, он очень красивый. неужели дело только в шрифте?

Comment: Покажи код описывающий элемент

Comment: Text("---",
maxLines: 3, 
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
textAlign: TextAlign.left, 
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, 
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело было в шрифте. Скачал его в другом месте.